# How to run OCaml + Core script?

Tags: ocaml

I am trying the Real World OCaml book. It talks about installing OPAM, then OCaml and Jane Street Core. I got utop loaded properly per the book instructions so that it automatically loads Core.

Without Core, I can run a generic OCaml script simply by `ocaml script.ml` without compiling. But this doesn't work if the script uses Core. What's the right command if I want to run a Core based OCaml script without compiling?

Answer (score 5):

Running a script that depends on additional libraries requires you to tell the compiler where to find the libraries. Your best option is to use `ocamlscript`, which you can also install with OPAM. Just do `opam install ocamlscript`. Then read about ocamlscript [here](http://mjambon.com/ocamlscript.html). Here's a working example:

```
$ cat a.ml
#! /usr/bin/env ocamlscript
Ocaml.ocamlflags := ["-thread"];
Ocaml.packs := [ "core" ]
--
open Core.Std

let () = print_endline "hello"
```

Make sure `a.ml` has the executable bit set. Then run it:

```
$ ./a.ml
hello
```

As a bonus, `ocamlscript` also compiles to native code, so you get high performance scripts.

Comment: I tried `ocamlscript`, but got the error: `"Cannot find file topfind."` And the `$OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH` is already set. Do you know how to fix this? Btw, I installed the `ocamlscript` with `opam 1.1.0`, and my `.ocamlinit` is like this:https://gist.github.com/seckcoder/8234822

Comment: That is strange. The .ocamlinit file is only loaded by the interactive toploop. OCamlscript doesn't load it, so I don't see why topfind is being searched for. Did you try exactly the example I provided? Also see my answer here[1].

[1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765452/ocaml-how-to-run-a-script-with-libraries-included/

Comment: Isn't `OCamlscript` just a wrapper around the OCaml toplevel runtime system? I have always thought `OCamlscript` will surely load `.ocamlinit`. Without using topfind, how could it open the other libraries like Core.Std? I'm not familiar with its implementation, so maybe I'm wrong. I've also asked a similar question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900465/ocaml-doesnt-load-ocamlinit-in-script-mode/20906386?noredirect=1#20906386 .

Comment: @WeiLi No, ocamlscript doesn't use the toplevel. You tell it, in the header of your script, what libraries you need to use. It then invokes the ocaml compiler with the appropriate flags.

Comment: The bug that @WeiLi ran into is due to using ocamlscript with the OPAM `system` switch.  If you do `opam switch 4.02.1` and compile a local compiler then it'll work.  The bug has been fixed upstream in ocamlscript and a new release requested that will fix it in https://github.com/mjambon/ocamlscript/commit/7b7af09024d3fab47be9ff84f4359737a1ff7717

Comment: topfind is a module provided by ocamlfind. You need to get it and compile it.