# OCaml: How to Run a Script with Libraries Included

Tags: ocaml

I'm following the Real World OCaml book to learn OCaml and many of the programs require using the Jane Street Core library. When I use functions from this core library in the toplevel, it works great. There, I just use the following commands to open the Core library.

```
$ #use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#camlp4o;;
#require "core.top";;
#require "core.syntax";;
open Core.Std;;
```

Then I can run this program line by line in the toplevel and functions like String.split work fine.

```
# let languages = "OCaml,Perl,C++,C";;
val languages : string = "OCaml,Perl,C++,C"
# let dashed_languages =
let language_list = String.split languages ~on:',' in
String.concat ~sep:"-" language_list
;;
val dashed_languages : string = "OCaml-Perl-C++-C"
```

But if I put it all in a script, how do I make the compiler recognize the core libraries? So if I'm running the same program in a script:

```
open Core.Std;;
open Str;;

let languages = "OCaml,Perl,C++,C";;
let dashed_languages =
    let language_list = String.split languages ~on:',' in
    String.concat ~sep:"-" language_list
;;
```

Then I compile it:

```
ocamlopt -o test test.ml
```

I get an error:

```
Error: Unbound module Core
```

So clearly Core is not being recognized. I can't put the #use and #require commands in my script because OCaml doesn't recognize those. So how can I use Core?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136420/how-to-run-ocaml-core-script

Comment: @clcto I recommended ocamlscript in that answer, but I'll provide another answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're following Real World OCaml, you may want to use `corebuild` to compile executables since this is what the book recommends. In this case the command `corebuild test.native` should correctly compile your script. If you use libraries other than Core, you'll need to specify them with the `-pkg` option.

Also, note you can omit the double semicolons within a `.ml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have ocamlfind. Also, make sure you have the right environment for it to find packages. If you installed with opam, run "eval `opam config env`". Then:

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -linkpkg -thread -package core test.ml -o test
```